# Принцип работы сверточной нейросети

Tags: нейронные-сети

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда CNN получает на вход изображения, она проходится 6 фильтрами по изображению и получается новая картинка глубиной 6. После чего идет слой пулинга, и вот когда идет второй слой свертки и у нас 16 фильров, мы берем один фильтр размером, например, 5*5 и берем часть картинки таких же размеров и в результате перемножаем фильтр с шестью матрицами части картинки (так как глубина 6), и после чего мы эти матрицы суммируем или просто записываем как 6 матриц для каждого из 16 фильтров?

Comment: Все, что до слоев с 'Full connection' - просто подготовка входных данных для трехслойного перцептрона.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, классическая сеть `LeNet-5` получает на вход картинку (градации серого, т.е. с одним цветовым каналом) размерности 32x32x1 (где 1 - это число каналов). Следовательно на первом шаге только один канал. Это можно рассматривать либо как 3D матрицу 1x32x32 или как 2D матрицу 32x32.

После *поэлементного* умножения окон (размерность плавающего окна равна размерности фильтра) всех слоев входящей матрицы (на данном шаге) на фильтр - результирующие ячейки суммируются.

В итоге после второй свертки из матрицы 6x14x14 после умножения на фильтр - получается один слой для каждого из 16 фильтров. Т.е. если рассмотреть только **один** фильтр на этом шаге, то из 3D матрицы 6x14x14 получается **одна** 2D матрица 10x10. Для 16 фильтров получаем 3D матрицу размерности 16x10x10 - по одному слою для каждого из 16 фильтров.